# Force SSL based on url pattern in Spring security 3.2?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ssl, spring-security

I am trying to configure my SS3.2 to do something quite simple: reject any HTTP request that's not directed at my login service; and allow access to the login service without authorization.

I have the following in my `security.xml`:

```
<http pattern="/login/**" security="none" />
<!--
    <intercept-url pattern="/login/**"  access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>
-->

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <custom-filter ref="myCustomFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</http>
```

Now since the login service will transport authentication information, it obviously needs to be secured by SSL/TLS. But I can't figure out how to force it to use SSL/TLS, while still letting it skip the custom filter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest that it's a bad idea. If your application needs HTTPS you should really use it throughout the entire session. That way you will also avoid things like secure/insecure cookie problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to force https for some pages in spring-security?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463103/is-there-any-way-to-force-https-for-some-pages-in-spring-security)

Comment: *"... allow access to the login service without authorization"* - Forgive my ignorance, but what does that mean? Access it without logging in? Isn't that how its supposed to work?